# How to check if facebook-video exists?

Tags: php, facebook, video

i am embedding facebook-videos into my website and i would like to find a way (in PHP) to check, if each video is still available or not. I would run the script via cronjob so that the videos embedded on the page are still working.
Is there a way i can access that through the fb API?